# Vite build hangs forever

Tags: build, vite, freeze, exit

when I run `vite build` aka `npm run build` the build performs without errors.

I see `built in 4661ms.` but the process never finishes. It just hangs.

How can I make the process end and exit?

Comment: Did you end up solving the issue? Your build process might be sending Vite into an exponentially growing — or infinite — loop. I experienced the same issue and I thought I'd share the result here in case it's useful to you or someone else reading this. In my case, it was my code making a PostCSS plugin generate a extremely large number of combinations of CSS rules. Assuming that the problem lies in the build process, you could simply try building the app incrementally by bringing one dependency at a time, narrowing down what part of your code makes Vite behave that way.

Comment: I have the same problem and currently I only try to fix this. The issue starts from vue 3.3.x version. On 3.2 was worked

Comment: If you use File system based routing, you can try my solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76281771/vite-build-command-hangs-at-modules-transformed-in-vue-3-3-4-vite-4-3-8-envi/76959690#76959690

Answer (score 7):

You can easily exit Vite by hooking into the [buildEnd](https://rollupjs.org/plugin-development/#buildend) and [closeBundle](https://rollupjs.org/plugin-development/#closebundle) events.

Define a plugin as follows:

```
// file vite-plugin-close.ts

export default function ClosePlugin() {
    return {
        name: 'ClosePlugin', // required, will show up in warnings and errors

        // use this to catch errors when building
        buildEnd(error) {
            if(error) {
                console.error('Error bundling')
                console.error(error)
                process.exit(1)
            } else {
                console.log('Build ended')
            }
        },

        // use this to catch the end of a build without errors
        closeBundle(id) {
            console.log('Bundle closed')
            process.exit(0)
        },
    }
}
```

Import the plugin in your `vite.config.ts`

```
// file vite.config.ts

import ClosePlugin from './vite-plugin-close.ts'
...

// place the plugin in the *vite* plugins section
// NOT the rollupOptions.plugins section
        plugins: [ClosePlugin()],
```

The same thing applies for JS files, just switch the extensions.

> ✓ 3662 modules transformed.
> dist/bundle/cli.js  8,825.66 kB
> Bundle closed
> (base) ➜  cli git:(main) ✗

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like `vite` is watching for changes.

If you have `build.watch` configured in `vite.config.ts`, running `vite build` will watch the project without explicitly specifying the `--watch` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the answers you can make the `watch` to `false`. So it will not continue to watch over your changes.

If you are using any process managers like `pm2` with `ecosystem.config.js` you have one more option:

- Stop the pm2 process, then run the command `npm run build`. It will build your app successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when running `npm run build` and I found out that in my `vite.config`, I had the `watch: true` value enabled for the template plugin. After removing this value, the production build of my application was successful and completed. So, it's likely that a watcher is also blocking you.

Hopefully, this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

Same thing. I've tried setting the npm script to each of the following:

```json
    "build": "vite build --ci",
    "build": "vite build --watch=false",
    "build": "vite build --watch false",
    "build": "vite build --mode staging",
    "build": "vite build --mode production",
    "build": "cross-env ci=true vite build",
    "build": "cross-env CI=true vite build",
    "build": "cross-env CI=true vite build --watch=false",
    "build": "cross-env DEV=true vite build",
    "build": "cross-env PROD=true vite build",
    "build": "cross-env production=true vite build",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=PROD vite build",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=PRODUCTION vite build",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=prod vite build",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production vite build",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=ci vite build",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=CI vite build",
```

And the build `vite.config.js` like so:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    watch: false
  }
});
```

But nothing works. `npm run build` always runs, finishes with `built in 4.79s` but never exits. But when I run it on GitHub Actions, it does finish. So not sure what the difference there is. I assumed it was looking for some environment variable or something, but nothing I tried worked locally.

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly the same problem.
I solved it by deleting this line here:

```js
import { io } from "./connection.js";
```

In fact, I couldn't import io because it didn't exist in my connection.js file. Consequently, it was impossible to finalize the build.