# Vite Build Command Hangs at 'modules transformed.' in Vue 3.3.4, Vite 4.3.8 Environment

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vite

"Hello, I'm currently working on a project using Vue 3.3.4, Vuetify 3.2.5, and Vite 4.3.8. When I run the vite build command, the process seems to hang and doesn't complete. The last output I see is:

```
✓ 679 modules transformed.
```

After this line, nothing else happens, and the build process doesn't finish. I've tried to look for solutions online, but I haven't found anything that addresses this specific issue.

Here are some additional details about my environment:

- Operating System: macOS 13.3.1 (a)(22E772610a)
- Node.js Version: 18.15.0

Additionally, all the packages in my package.json file are up-to-date:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@casl/ability": "^6.2.0",
    "@casl/vue": "^2.2.0",
    "@floating-ui/dom": "^1.2.7",
    "@mdi/font": "^7.0.96",
    "@vueuse/core": "^10.1.2",
    "@vueuse/math": "^10.1.2",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.21.2",
    "firebase": "^9.19.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "pinia": "^2.0.24",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "postcss-sorting": "^8.0.2",
    "prismjs": "^1.29.0",
    "sass": "^1.56.1",
    "stylelint-order": "^6.0.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.45",
    "vue-flatpickr-component": "^11.0.3",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.2.2",
    "vue-prism-component": "^2.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.5",
    "vue3-perfect-scrollbar": "^1.6.0",
    "vuetify": "^3.0.3",
    "webfontloader": "^1.6.28"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@antfu/eslint-config-vue": "^0.38.5",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^6.1.6",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^6.1.6",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^6.1.6",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^6.1.6",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^6.1.6",
    "@fullcalendar/vue3": "^6.1.6",
    "@iconify-json/mdi": "^1.1.35",
    "@iconify/tools": "^2.1.2",
    "@iconify/vue": "^4.1.1",
    "@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n": "^0.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.7.18",
    "@types/webfontloader": "^1.6.34",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.43.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.43.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.2.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8.38.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-sonarjs": "^0.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-unicorn": "^46.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.10.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^12.0.0",
    "postcss-html": "^1.5.0",
    "prettier": "^2.8.7",
    "stylelint": "^15.6.1",
    "stylelint-config-idiomatic-order": "^9.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard-scss": "^9.0.0",
    "stylelint-use-logical-spec": "^5.0.0",
    "type-fest": "^3.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4",
    "unplugin-auto-import": "^0.15.3",
    "unplugin-vue-components": "^0.24.1",
    "vite": "^4.3.4",
    "vite-plugin-pages": "^0.29.0",
    "vite-plugin-vue-layouts": "^0.8.0",
    "vite-plugin-vuetify": "^1.0.2",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.0.9"
  }
```

If anyone has encountered a similar issue with any of these packages, or if there's something that stands out as a potential issue, I would really appreciate your insights. Thank you again!"

- Before updating all packages to their latest versions, I didn't encounter this issue.
- I've tried deleting node_modules and reinstalling the packages.
- The vite --host command works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Simply downgrade vue to vue@^3.2 and pinia to pinia@^2.0

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks bud. I spent hours trying to fix this issue. How did you find out that this was problem?

Answer (score 3):

According to your dependencies, I recognized your template (vuexy or similar?) and because I use it too I had the same problem for so long and I finally solved it.

After update to Vue 3.3 you should refactor your File system based routing from vite-plugin-pages and vue-router to unplugin-vue-router including AutoImport setting in Vite config.

So, I'll try to explain with an example:

**router/index.ts**

```js
import routes from '~pages'

...

const router = createRouter({
...
  routes: [
    ...setupLayouts(routes),
  ],
})
```

**vite.config.ts**

```js
import Pages from 'vite-plugin-pages'

...

      AutoImport({
        imports: [..., 'vue-router', ... ]
```

These lines are the cause, even though the vite debug logs won't tell about it.

So, finally you can try like this:

**router/index.ts**

```js
import { setupLayouts } from 'virtual:generated-layouts'
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router/auto'

function recursiveLayouts(route) {
  if (route.children) {
    for (let i = 0; i < route.children.length; i++)
      route.children[i] = recursiveLayouts(route.children[i])

    return route
  }

  return setupLayouts([route])[0]
}

...

const router = createRouter({
  ...

  extendRoutes: pages => [
    ...pages.map(route => recursiveLayouts(route)),
  ],
})
```

**vite.config.ts**

```js
import { VueRouterAutoImports, getPascalCaseRouteName } from 'unplugin-vue-router'
import VueRouter from 'unplugin-vue-router/vite'

...
// plugins: 

    VueRouter({
      getRouteName: routeNode => {
        // Convert pascal case to kebab case
        return getPascalCaseRouteName(routeNode)
          .replace(/([a-z0-9])([A-Z])/g, '$1-$2')
          .toLowerCase()
      },
    }),

...

 AutoImport({
      imports: [..., VueRouterAutoImports, ...]
```

Comment: Hey there,  thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately this didn't work in my case, the build it's still stuck in the same place. Do you know any way to debug what might be the case for this? Also I find it amazing you recognized the template used by the package json LOL. I also tried removing any unused pages/components/packages but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 3):

If you really are using a template from vuexy, the error lies in their `default.vue` layout.

In my case it looked like this:

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { useSkins } from '@/app/composable/useSkins'
import { useThemeConfig } from '@/app/composable/useThemeConfig'

// @layouts plugin
import { AppContentLayoutNav } from '@/modules/navigation/enums'

const DefaultLayoutWithVerticalNav = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('./components/DefaultLayoutWithVerticalNav.vue'))

const { appContentLayoutNav } = useThemeConfig()

const { layoutAttrs, injectSkinClasses } = useSkins()

injectSkinClasses()
</script>

<template>
  <template v-if="appContentLayoutNav === AppContentLayoutNav.Vertical">
    <DefaultLayoutWithVerticalNav v-bind="layoutAttrs" />
  </template>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
// As we are using `layouts` plugin we need its styles to be imported
@use "@layouts/styles/_default-layout";
</style>
```

You should change the import of the `DefaultLayoutWithVerticalNav` component from

```
const DefaultLayoutWithVerticalNav = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('./components/DefaultLayoutWithVerticalNav.vue'))
```

to (in your case path may be different)

```
import DefaultLayoutWithVerticalNav from '@/layouts/components/DefaultLayoutWithVerticalNav.vue'
```

For me this solves the problem and the build command no longer hangs.

Comment: Yes, it works. But I noticed template authors were able to make defineAsyncComponent work for Vite builds